# Ruby on Rails. How do I change view file in production without restarting server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I made feature that allows to change one of view files through browser.
It changes file and doesn't use DB. In development mode all works well.
But as far as I know rails caches all files in production mode.

Does somebody know solution?

I have found this post
http://railshints.tumblr.com/post/1559660060/reload-rails-templates-dynamically-in-production-mode  but it seems not work or I do something wrong.

I use Rails 2.3.5

Comment: If you change the file and it's update date changes are you sure that Rails doesn't fetch it instead of using the cache?

Comment: Yes. It needs some time before page's changes will be visible.